# Ivy + SBT .12.2 + Play Framework 2.1 - Resolving External Ivy File

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, sbt, ivy

I want to use SBT .12.2 to resolve the dependencies listed in an external ivy.xml file, such that my Play application can resolve at compile/runtime. I am using the IvyDE plugin for eclipse, and Ivy can by itself resolve the dependencies in the ivy.xml file.

I attempted to [follow these docs](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.2/docs/Detailed-Topics/Library-Management.html), so this is my current Build.scala:

```
object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

    val appName = "App"
    val appVersion = "{VERSION}"

    val appDependencies = Seq(
        javaCore,
        javaJdbc,
        javaEbean
    )

    resolvers += Resolver.file("Local repo", file(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/.ivy2/local"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)
    externalIvySettingsURL(url("file://L:/Utils/ivySettings/ivysettings.xml"))
    externalIvyFile( baseDirectory { base => base / "ivy.xml"} )

    classpathConfiguration in Compile := config("play")
    classpathConfiguration in Test := config("play")
    classpathConfiguration in Runtime := config("play")


    val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(

    )
}
```

and my ivy.xml:

```
<ivy-module version="2.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
     xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/schemas/ivy.xsd">

    <info
        organisation="Company"
        module="App"
        status="Integration">
    </info>

    <configurations>
        <conf name="sources" description="Sources of this library" />
        <conf name="play" description="Building our play library" />  
        <conf name="test" description="Building our test library" />  
    </configurations>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency org="Apache" name="elasticsearch" rev="2.1.0" />
        <dependency org="Apache" name="json-simple" rev="1.1.1" />          
        <!-- Used for testing -->
        <dependency org="Apache" name="Selenium" rev="2.42" conf="test->default" />     
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

When i spin up Play, and call the `dependencies` command, I do not see these dependencies listed, and they are not present at runtime. The only files that Play can see are the ones defined in appDependencies. I am using a non-standard versioning pattern, but I should at least be able to see the dependencies fail to be found if my settings file wasn't getting picked up.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, most of my initial syntax from the documentation was close, but I wasn't applying any of those settings in the context of my Play project. In addition, I wasn't pointing my resolver to the correct directory. My ivy.xml file was fine.

```
  val appName         = "My-Application"
  val appVersion    = ".1"

  val appDependencies = Seq(
    javaCore,
    javaJdbc,
    javaEbean
  )
    resolvers += Resolver.file("Local repo", file("C:/Utils/lib"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)

    val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
        externalIvySettingsURL(url("file:///C:/Utils/ivySettings/ivysettings-ian.xml")),
        externalIvyFile(),
        classpathConfiguration in Compile := config("play"),
        classpathConfiguration in Test := config("play"),
        classpathConfiguration in Runtime := config("play"),
        organization := "Company"
    )
```

SBT will resolve the dependencies ONLY in the `ivy.xml` file, so you need to add the dependencies from `javaCore`, `javaJdbc`, and `javaEbean` to your ivy file for resolution. Other sticking points include noting the three slashes for the file descriptor.